# Customized input

Tags: html, css

I need to add form fields like this to my feedback
[image]

What kind of `input` do I need to use and how can I make it look like above?

Comment: I'm thinking about <img> <input> <img> ...

Comment: You can use images. Split the parts of you input and create the corresponding images.Then with css you may achieve the exact layout and with js you will capture the ui events on the controls,e.g.click on a button, and act accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've mashed something up on JSfiddle. It's just an example and you're supposed to do the fine-tuning yourself:

http://jsfiddle.net/AvAV3/

```
   <div class="rate">
       <ul>
           <li class="selected"></li>
           <li class="selected"></li>
           <li class="selected"></li>
           <li class="selected"></li>
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
       </ul>
       <br />
       <a class="minus" href="#">-</a> <input class="number" type="text" /> <a class="plus" href="#">+</a>
       <span>Kazaar</span>
</div>


body {
 background-color: #000000;   
}

.number {
width: 30px;
}

.minus, .plus {
 font-size: 15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color: #3E3935;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding:3px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.rate {
width: 100px;
}
.rate input {
 background-color: #ccc;   
    border:0;
    height: 22px;

}
.rate > span {
display: block;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 17px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 10px;
}
.rate > ul {
list-style-type: none;
width: 100%;
height: 0px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
.rate > ul li {
 background-color: #A2A19F;   
 display: inline-block;
padding:3px;
    margin: -1px;
}

.rate > ul li.selected {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;   
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use mobile jqueryui and

```html
<input type="button" class="ui-icon-plus">
<input type="button" class="ui-icon-minus">
```

```css
.ui-icon-plus{}
.ui-icon-minus{}
```

this icon will automatic generator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two buttons and a textbox for each field. Styling can be done by CSS as you probably know. The little bar above can be a list or something and the text below can be a label. Of course, there are many options.

Answer (score -2):

I would use a normal `<input type="number">` with :before and :after.

Comment: It is not really a cross browser option.

Comment: Otherwise there has to be much javascript.

Comment: Yep.. but this way FireFox will be out because it doesn't support it.

Comment: Not really, I'm not OP. But all I'm saying is this is not the best solution.